# Портирование игры с java на android

Tags: android, java

Делал игру по гайду от Kilobolt и сделал сначала игру на java.
При попытке перенести по гайду на андроид заметил, что многих методов из java.awt.* в android попросту нету. Есть ли альтернатива пакету java.awt.Graphics?

Вот как пример метод в java

```
public void paintItBlack(Graphics g) {
        if (currentRoom>=0) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1024, 640);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @dante4001, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Android имеет свои библиотеки для работы с графикой. Находятся они в пакете android.graphics. Вот ссылка с официального сайта [Android Graphics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html)

Попробуйте посмотреть методы и классы данного пакета.
Есть еще портированная библиотека, но к сожалению, уже устаревшая и не поддерживается.

[COMPAT AWT Library](https://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/)

Comment: > COMPAT AWT Library
судя по тому что там написано я бы не стал ею пользоваться

Comment: > но к сожалению, уже устаревшая и не поддерживается. 
Я же предупредил)